# Reading external XML File on .NET for Windows Phone in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing, windows-phone

im trying to parse an **external** XML file in C# on .net for WP so does anyone know an equivalent for `XmlUrlResolver` in .net for WP ?

Answer (score 0):

adapt this code for your use, use it to read a file in JSON. It's basically the same procedure.

```
private void Function()
        {
                string url = String.Format("**your xaml string here**");
                try
                {
                    destination = null;
                    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(EndFunction);
                    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
                }
                catch
                {
                    ///todo: criar if para verificar conexão   
                    MessageBox.Show("Verify your connection and try again!");
                }
        }




 private void EndFunction(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {            
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Verify your connection and try again!");
            }
            else
            {
                // Save the feed into the State property in case the application is tombstoned. 
                this.State["xml"] = e.Result;
                x = ParserXML(e.Result);                
            }
        }
```